# In this sentence, does the word "as" make it sound like the speaker was the leader?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, word-order

> Oh, to illustrate the frustration as the leader, for the fifth year changed the rules; I could barely nod my head!

Comment: Presumably there's a bit more context you could add to the quote (including its source, which is customary and helpful). As it is, there are quite a number of interpretations.

Comment: A young man explains to his father the circumstances that led him to resign his position.  He describes his response when his superior told him the society would no longer aid children over the age of 10. "Oh, to illustrate the frustration as the leader, for the fifth year changed the rules; I could barely nod my head!" (Is this what you are asking?)

Comment: Please **edit the question** to include context: comments are ephemeral and it shouldn't be necessary to read them all to gain information about the question. And please cite where it comes from: how English is used has changed over the last 200 years (and even within the last 50).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You don't explain why you imagine there would be such an implication, but I hazard that you have misunderstood the construction. It is not *He as leader changed the rules* (since rule-changing was the leader's prerogative), but *(I had to stand and watch) as he changed the rules*; *as* could be replaced by *when* or *while*.

Edit after due consideration; if the sentence stopped at the semicolon, it would be theoretically possible that *the fifth year* was the subject of 'changed the rules', in which case the speaker would indeed have to be the leader (though *the* should have been omitted after *as*). This is not a construction that would occur to a native speaker; any such would automatically assume that it was the leader who changed the rules, and either a comma should be inserted after *year*, or the comma after *leader* should be omitted.

Comment: It's 85% probable that you're completely right. If more context and explanation were given in OPs, one wouldn't have to take so many risks with answers.

Comment: There is more context in the comments. I suppose I *could* have edited that into the question.